# Creating a dropdown menu using CSS and HTML

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I am trying to make a navigation bar with a four columns submenus. I coded most of things, but when I creating the submenu I found the problem.

This is my HTML:

```
<div id="navigation">
    <ul>
        <li class="current">
            <a href="" class="">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="sub-menu">
            <a href="">Our Products</a>
            <div class="subnav product">
                <div class="content">
                    <div class="col">
                        <ul>
                            <li class="one">
                                <a href="">Main Menu Item</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="one">
                                <a href="">Main Menu Item</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="one">
                                <a href="">Main Menu Item</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <ul>
                            <li class="two">
                                <img src="" />
                                <a href="">Promoting Peace in the Niger Delta</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="three">
                                <img src="" />
                                <a href="">Promoting Peace in the Niger Delta</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="four">
                                <img src="" />
                                <a href="">Promoting Peace in the Niger Delta</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="five">
                                <img src="" />
                                <a href="">Promoting Peace in the Niger Delta</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="">
            <a href="">Service Maintenance</a>
        </li>
        <li class="sub-menu">
            <a href="">Frequently Ask Questions</a>
        <li class="sub-menu">
            <a href="">Our Products</a>
            <div class="subnav product">
                <div class="content">
                    <div class="col">
                        <ul>
                            <li class="one">
                                <a href="">Main Sub Item</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="one">
                                <a href="">Main Sub Item</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="one">
                                <a href="">Main Sub Item</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>               
</div>
```

Hope somebody will help me out. 
Thank you.

Comment: how I create 4 columns in my dropdown? I tried with `float` but it didn't work for me

Comment: `float: left` works http://jsfiddle.net/qtvVK/6/ I didn't fix the whole thing but the reason it's not working is because the parent `<div>` container wasn't wide enough to contain the elements.  Adjust that and your text and it'll work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/qtvVK/11/embedded/result/.

I made some changes to your markup and used `display:inline-block;` instead of floating elements

Relevant CSS syles

```
/* Dropdown styles */
 #navigation ul > li > ul.sub-menu {
    display: none;
    position:absolute;
    padding:10px 0;
    background:#fff;
    border: 1px solid #DDDCDC;
    top: 24px;
    z-index: 1;
}
/* Show dropdown when hover */
 #navigation ul > li:hover > ul.sub-menu {
    display:block;
}
.row {
    width:auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.col {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is the container width is defined at 300px

```
#navigation ul li > div.product {
    width: 300px;
}
```

And its child elements are taking up 100% of that space. So you need to make sure they have room to float left.

```
#navigation div.col {
float: left;
    height:200px;
    width: 25%;
}
```

Hopefully that helps with your question.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qtvVK/4/)

Comment: but this rule is not working `#navigation ul li.sub-menu > div.subnav > div.content > div.col ul li:last-child  { 
 display: inline; 
}`

Comment: Can you be more specific about the intended behavior?

Comment: Ajak thanks for your answer. I have another case, when I click or mouse over on main navigation item it displays my submenu but there is a line appear between two and when I mouse remove from main menu item then other menu items moving little. can you tell me how I fix these problem?

Comment: I think I understand. The reason for this is because of the width is 300px. Its rendering the elements as display inline still, but since your container isn't big enough for the picture + the text its pushing it underneath. If you set the width of the container from 300 to something like 1500px you can see that it is still working. Hope that helps in your debuging.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest using jQuery.
it has simple function called slideDown().
[Here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_slide.asp) is a link to a good tutorial.

You should do like so: First hide your menu when script starts:

```
$("#idOfDropDownMenu").hide();
```

And command to drop menu down when mouse enters button and slide up when it leaves it:

```
$("#idOfButton").hover(function(){      //function that fires when mouse enters
    $("#idOfDropDownMenu").slideDown();
}, function() {                         //function that fires when mouse leaves
    $("#idOfDropDownMenu").slideUp();
}
```

Instead of using IDs you can use any CSS selector.

I hope this helps with your question.

Answer (score 0):

css

```
ul li ul
{
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    margin-left: 191px;
    margin-top: -37px; 
}
ul li:hover ul
{
    display: block; 
}

ul li a:hover
{
    color: #fff;
    background: #939393;
    border-radius:20px;
}

 ul li a
{
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    color: #333;
    background: #f2f2f2;
    text-decoration: none;

}
ul
{
   background: #f2f2f2;
   list-style:none;
   padding-left: 1px;
   width: 194px;
   text-align: center;

}
```

html

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
   <li>
      <a href="#">About</a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href="#">About Me</a>
         <li><a href="#">About Site</a>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```